# How to have a condition within COUNT

Tags: mysql, sql

Im trying to get the proportion of two numbers by having a condition within the count clause, but it just returns the same number no matter what the condition is:

```
SELECT COUNT(type=2)/COUNT(type=3) as Proportion
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `SUM` instead of `COUNT`.

```
SELECT SUM(type=2)/SUM(type=3) as Proportion
```

because `count` counts both the failed and true conditions (1&0 are returned for the condition for true&false), while `sum` sums up only true values.